# Android JSON iterator of the same keys

Tags: java, android, json

I have this xml and I convert in JSON programmatically:

```
<channel>
<title></title>
<link>index.html</link>
<description>...</description>
<language></language>
<copyright>© Copyright</copyright>
<atom:link href="www.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<image>...</image>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</channel>
```

I need iterator into "item" keys.. But on JsonArray I get catch JSONException error.
So.. How I can iterator a JSON with the same keys?

I create the JSON code with XmlToJson lib, and use this code to make the array:

```
JSONObject jitem = new JSONObject(xmlToJson.toString());
           jitem = new JSONObject(jitem.getString("rss"));
           JSONArray channel = new JSONArray(jitem.getString("channel"));
```

Comment: How are you converting it?

Comment: show us the JSON you create from the xml and we might be able to help. I suspect you've got multiple 'item' keys instead of an items array, which is what you should create if possible.

Comment: I convert programatically, but JSON appears correctly. Inside "item" I have other keys.

Comment: Are you asking about the JSON that "appears correctly". If so, show it to us. --- Are you asking about the conversion process? Is so, show it to us. --- In short, show the *relevant* part that you are asking us about. --- *FYI:* The XML doesn't have "keys", so when you say *"I need iterator into "item" keys"* is sounds like you're asking about processing JSON, in which case the XML is immaterial and we wonder why you showed it to us in the first place.

Comment: dude, json is huge, can not log.i in it whole, but I'll edit the part that matters.

Comment: you cant iterate channel since it is not an array. Item is just another object as far as the json parser is concerned. If each channel object has a set amount of elements you can just iterate through the channel object, skip till the items and then get the values

Answer (score 0):

Since the item names are the same. I think the easiest way for you would be to use a Iterater to iterate over the Json object.

Here is the basic code to do this

```
//create the json object that you want to iterate thorugh
JSONObject jitem = new JSONObject(xmlToJson.toString());
jitem = new JSONObject(jitem.getString("rss"));
Iterator<?> keys = jitem.keys();
//use a while loop to iterate thorugh the object
while( keys.hasNext() ) {
String key = (String)keys.next();
if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
//TODO:
//add a if statement here to check if this json object is a item object
//if it is a item object then do your work here
}
}
```

This is the cleanest way to do it bar for using a library such as GSON to deserialize it